# play framework 2.1 junit test not working from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

im following the zentask tutorial and wrote a junit test,
the test wont run from the eclipse IDE its giving the following exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class [class play.db.ebean.Model] is enhanced and [class models.User] is not - (you can not mix!!)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1475)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1138)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1058)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:252)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:210)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)
```

I read a bit and found that for some people
editing the buils.scala adding the following line inside main helped : ebeanEnabled := true

to me it didnt nither closeing the ide running play clean compile

any ideas???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is [blog post](http://blog.matthieuguillermin.fr/2012/03/unit-testing-tricks-for-play-2-0-and-ebean/) about setting up unit tests to run in IDEs. It suggests to add following command-line to java used when running tests:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/ebean/ebean-2.7.3-agent.jar
```

Seems that Play not ships with ebean agent, it should be downloaded from Ebean website first (in main ebean package).

I not tried it.

[Ebean user guide](http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf) also mentions it (*15.5.2 javaagent* section), there is even example for configuring Eclipse.

Also, to speed up enhancement maybe this will be better:

```
-javaagent:/path/to/ebean/ebean-2.7.3-agent.jar;packages=models.*
```

So it will only look into `models.*` (default package for ORM models in Play).

Comment: I tried this in Play 2.1.5 using avaje-ebeanorm-agent-3.2.2.jar but it doesn't seem to do much other than give this message in the console: transform> cls: play/db/ebean/Model msg: ... ignore field _ebean_intercept

Comment: @Splaktar please use the jar ebean-2.7.3-agent.jar from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/avaje/ebean/2.7.3/ and this will work ( right now with play 2.2.6)

Comment: Upgraded to Play 2.3.7 and now everything is working!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Avaje Ebean Eclipse Plugin:

http://www.avaje.org/eclipseupdate/site.xml

After the installation, activate Ebean enhancement by right clicking on your project and selecting Enable Ebean Enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error when i tried to remove the public modifier from the declaration of one of classes extending Model.

i was using a model to make a "through" table (a many to many relationship with additional information), so protected access makes sense.  perhaps there's another way to do this, but the play javadoc is pretty sparse.