# Play 2 - Zentask Java Tutorial - jUnit ebean test failure

Tags: java, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, junit4

> > **Solution: you dont need IDE for testing, just run "play test" in the console**

Good Evening!
I just started to get into Play Framework, I worked with jUnit before and also used testing in rails and lift. But here I think there is a problem with ebean, and I just dont get why it happens. 
I use eclipse and the right java versions, all libraries are fine, no errors in the code, i just follow the tutorial. Solutions like adding ebean into VM dont work, cause it says then "cant load VM" on eclipse.

there is the error message

```
[[31merror[0m] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Error in deployment
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class [class play.db.ebean.Model] is enhanced and [class models.User] is not - (you can not mix!!)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1475) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1138) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1058) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:252) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124) [avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class [class play.db.ebean.Model] is enhanced and [class models.User] is not - (you can not mix!!)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.checkInheritedClasses(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1528) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.checkSubclass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1491) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1450) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1138) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1058) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-server.jar:na]
```

I think this is the main error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class [class play.db.ebean.Model] is enhanced and [class models.User] is not - (you can not mix!!)
```

I hope you guys can help me out quick!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the eclipse ide
to get it working just follow the instructions in my question here:

[play framework 2.1 junit test not working from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913627/play-framework-2-1-junit-test-not-working-from-eclipse)

cheers

Comment: are you sure you followed every step? i had the exact same problem and it resolved it to me