# Eclipse - jUnit Tests not working because of Ebean

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to run the tests for my play 2.2.1 application from withing Eclipse. They are currently not working because of a weird Ebean error that occurs when I run the tests from eclipse.

The Tests are working perfectly fine when I run them from the command line with "play testOnly ...".

I've looked at another solution of that problem ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913627/play-framework-2-1-junit-test-not-working-from-eclipse)) and I did already add `-javaagent:C:\Java\play-2.2.1\repository\local\org.avaje.ebeanorm\avaje-ebeanorm-agent\3.2.1\jars\avaje-ebeanorm-agent.jar` as a default VM argument in Eclipse. I verified that eclipse is in fact using that jar file since it complains when I point it to a non-existing jar file.

The error message in the eclipse console is: `transform> cls: play/db/ebean/Model  msg: ... ignore field _ebean_intercept`. The full error output is [here](http://pastebin.com/EQSqiahQ).

This is the error message that junit displays:

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.Game] in Ebean server]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92)
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570)
at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:298)
at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:71)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:359)
at play.test.WithApplication.start(WithApplication.java:18)
at models.GameTest.setUp(GameTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    models/Game.validate()Ljava/lang/String; @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'models/Team' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'models/Game'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'models/Game' }
    stack: { 'models/Team' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab6 0059 b600 5d2a b600 60b6 005d a600
    0000010: 0612 26b0 01b0                         
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@20)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:69)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: I fought with this a few months ago and finally gave up.  Most of my code is in a separate service layer that is easily unit tested anyway.  I believe upcoming Play releases 2.4 will simplify unit testing by adding dependency injection, and some of these issues may go away.  Your other choice is to not use EBean which does bytecode enhancement (which can conflict with Play's compilation strategy).